# How do I make tests dependent using nested test execution in mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I have a simple example of two tests (A,B) where B depends on A being run.

If I am using Mocha, I can nest test B within A:

```
describe.only( 'AB:', function() {

    describe( 'A', function() {
        it( 'A1', function() {
            assert.equal( 1, 2 );
        } );

        describe( 'B', function() {
            it( 'B1', function() {
                assert.equal( 1, 1 );
            } );
        } );
    } );
} );
```

But both A and B are run even if A fails.

How is this any different than not using nesting?

```
describe.only( 'AB:', function() {

    describe( 'A&B', function() {
        it( 'A1', function() {
            assert.equal( 1, 2 );
        } );

        it( 'B1', function() {
            assert.equal( 1, 1 );
        } );
    } );
} );
```

Is there any way to skip B if A fails?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use [mocha-steps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-steps):

```
describe('my smoke test', function() {
 
  step('login', function() {
  });
 
  step('buy an item', function() {
    throw new Error('failed');
  });
 
  step('check my balance', function() {
  });
 
  xstep('temporarily ignored', function() {
  });
 
});
```

Full blog post [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180704060034/https://watirmelon.blog/2018/07/04/bailing-with-mocha-e2e-tests/).

Answer (score 9):

Ok, there are two questions, so I'll try to answer both.

1. > Is there any way to skip B if A fails?

   Generally you should write tests that are not dependent on each other.

   Sometimes tests depend on having certain setup or state before they're able to be run properly though, in which case it's best to do the setup in a `before()` or `beforeEach()` block. If either of these blocks fail, the tests after them are not run. Thus you can throw an error in those blocks, when your build up is in a way that you know none of the tests inside that describe block are not going to work.

   ```
   describe.only('AB:', function() {
     var numberUnderTest = 0;

     describe('A&B', function() {
       it('A1', function() {
         assert.equal(1, 1 * numberUnderTest);
       });

       describe('B', function() {
         before(function() {
           if (numberUnderTest === 0) {
             throw 'cannot divide by zero';
           }
         });

         it('B1', function() {
           assert.equal(1, 1 / numberUnderTest);
         });
       });
     });
   });
   ```
2. > If I am using Mocha, I can nest test B within A
   >   [...]
   >   How is this any different than not using nesting?

   Nesting B inside a describe block allows you to use a different setup for B1 than for A1, while still inheriting some of A's setup.

   ```
   describe('A', function() {
     var numberUnderTest;
     var anotherNumber;

     beforeEach(function() {
       numberUnderTest = 1;
       anotherNumber = 0;
     });

     it('A1'), function() {
       assert.equal(0, anotherNumber * numberUnderTest);
     });

     describe('B', function() {
       before(function() {
         anotherNumber = 1;
       });

       it('B1', function() {
         assert.equal(1, anotherNumber / numberUnderTest);
       });
     });
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I understand tests should be independent which is what we do for unit tests, but we're also writing end-to-end tests in Mocha which is why I've asked this question about dependent steps.

Comment: Well, as far as I know, you can't tell Mocha to fail other tests when one fails directly. But as a workaround you could use a boolean variable that you update during the first test and add a `before` block in front of all the dependent tests that throws error, if the first test failed.

Comment: @AlisterScott I came across this question with the same need, to run tests step by step for an end-to-end test. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @rhlsthrm we wrote a fork which allows this, it won't be accepted by Mocha but we use it anyway: https://github.com/Automattic/mocha

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to skip B if A fails?

This pattern has been working very fell for me:

```
var itCanLogin;

it('Can login', function() {
  ...

  itCanLogin = true;
});

it('Can Logout', function(){
   if(!itCanLogin) this.skip()

   ...
})
```

Could also use `assert(itCanLogin)` but `this.skip()` helps to keep output cleaner by not producing stacktraces & errors - easier to notice the source of problem this way.

Comment: I am now using mocha-steps (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-steps) - full explanation here: https://watirmelon.blog/2018/07/04/bailing-with-mocha-e2e-tests/

Answer (score 0):

```
Use try Catch! - Set a flag (array) and check in any subsequent tests if it 
is set to Fail then skip the test.

try{
var pageTitle = await ndp.currTitle();
await pageTitle.should.equal('Google');  
}
catch (e) {
testStatus[0] === 'Fail'
assert.fail('1st Test Failed due to error --> ' +e);
}
<<Subsequent Test>>

if (testStatus[0] === 'Fail')
{
    this.skip();
}

you can also check this flag for any other test too in the same module, 
testStatus[0], testStatus[1] etc wt different status. Make it dynamic using 
a counter etc...
```